# Does Java offer a way to allow special access from Packages along the Hierarchy?

Tags: java, package, access-modifiers, class-hierarchy

Does Java Package hierarchy affect the access right of classes and variables?

About Java Package: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Please take a look at this line:

> ... The second column indicates whether classes in the same package as the class (**regardless of their parentage**) have access to the member. ...

As far as i know, `package com.google` and `package com.google.music` are two separate packages. They have absolutely no connections. Their differences are just like the differences between `package com.google` and `package com.yahoo`.

Is this true?

Is there a way, or a keyword (public, private, protected, etc.), which can make the relations between `package com.google` and `package com.google.music` closer?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java Language Specification [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.1):

> The hierarchical naming structure for packages is intended to be convenient for organizing related packages in a conventional manner, but has no significance in itself other than the prohibition against a package having a subpackage with the same simple name as a top level type (§7.6) declared in that package.
>
> *For example, there is no special access relationship between a package named oliver and another package named oliver.twist, or between packages named evelyn.wood and evelyn.waugh. That is, the code in a package named oliver.twist has no better access to the types declared within package oliver than code in any other package.*

That is, how you nest your packages has no effect on the semantics of a program.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, there isn't such keyword. In java there are 4 access levels:

- public
- protected
- private
- default (package access, other class in the same package has access to that property).